# yocto linux: can't include TUN/TAP kernel driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I'm using Yocto to build a custom linux image for a zedboard. I need to run openVPN on the Zedboard, which requires access to the TUN/TAP virtual network interface. I successfully incorporated openVPN and all its dependencies into my image using the meta-networking layer, but it appears that the necessary TUN/TAP kernel drivers are not present in the image.

**How can I ensure that the TUN/TAP kernel drivers are included in my image?**

I have the following two lines in my conf/local.conf file:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-modules"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "openssl openvpn docker tunctl`

I don't know how I could include them in my (otherwise plain) linux-xlnx kernel. I tried adding `kernel-module-tun` to my `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` as mentioned [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2014-September/021698.html), but it does not appear this is a valid package provided by any of my layers.

I also tried using bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel to manual include the modules in the image, however after doing this and rerunning bitbake core-image-minimal I still did not see tun.ko appear in either of the two locations below that I would expect them to be installed to...

```
${BUILDDIR}/tmp/work/zedboard_zynq7-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs/lib/modules/4.6.0-xilinx-v2016.3/kernel/net/
```

or

```
${BUILDDIR}/tmp/work/zedboard_zynq7-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-xlnx/4.6-xilinx-v2016.3+gitAUTOINC+0e4e407149-r0/image/lib/modules/4.6.0-xilinx-v2016.3/kernel/net
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you really building the `tun` module`? If so, adding`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "kernel-module-tun"` should have worked for you.

Try running:

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig
```

and verify that you're building the `tun` module.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I already tried to use menuconfig and the TUN module is not being built. Is there a way to add it to the build without using menuconfig?

Comment: The easiest thing is to run `menuconfig`. If you know the exact configuration, you could always create a config fragment, see http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#changing-the-configuration.